# Exporting HTML table data to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have JSON data that I bind to a table:

[image]

Now I would like to export this data to Excel, so I have written this code that involves data formatting of an Excel spreadsheet.

```
private static MemoryStream JsonToStream<T>(string data, string html, string movieReportName)        
{
    IEnumerable<T> serializedData = data.JsonDeserialize<T>().AsEnumerable<T>();
    List<SelectListItem> colOrder = ParseColumnsToList(html);
    DataTable dataTable = serializedData.ToDataTable<T>(colOrder);
    ExcelPackage epackage = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet excel = epackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(movieReportName);
    excel.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

    int rowCount = dataTable.Rows.Count;
    int columnCount = dataTable.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 2; i < rowCount + 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= columnCount; j++)
        {
           if (value.Contains("%"))
            {
                if ((dataTable.Columns[j - 1].ColumnName != "Movie Code") {

                    value = value.Replace("%", "");
                    if (value.Contains("."))
                    {
                        double number = 0.0;
                        double.TryParse(value, out number);
                        excel.Cells[i, j].Value = number / 100;
                        excel.Cells[i, j].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00##%";
                    }
                }
            }
         }
      }
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(epackage.GetAsByteArray());
      epackage.Dispose();
      return ms;
  }
```

This works fine but it runs very slowly. Do you think I have to move data formatting to a database?

**Update**
What are different better option to export large data from HTML to excel?

Comment: What you need to do is to disable calculation and screen updating for as long as the loops are running. See my answer to [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153407/59161) question.

Comment: It says "Application" is does not exist in the context.  Is Application.EnableEvents = False is part of csharp?

Comment: Why would a method called `JsonToStream` be doing anything at all in excel or data tables? Very misleading!

Comment: I don't think moving formatting to database is the answer.  Figure out which line(s) are causing the slowness.

Comment: @eurotrash, because string "data" is in json format.

Comment: As I've said, as long as Excel is refreshing after every single cell update it will remain slow, no matther how you optimize the code. You need to turn off updating. Perhaps `EnableEvents` isn't available via interop but I'm sure there are other options you can use. My link was about VBA but the APIs are not that different.

Comment: @codetoshare That doesn't answer the question. This is what I expect the method to do based on its name: take JSON data as input, return it as a stream. Yet it goes off and does stuff in excel?? You're putting too much functionality in this method. Single Responsibility applies to methods too. Your method is doing too many things. A method called `JsonToStream` should *only* convert JSON to a stream.

Answer (score 1):

First off let's encapsulate what you are trying to do here.

Create a function that will format the DataTable.

```
private static DataTable FormatMovieReportTable(DataTable reportTable)
{
    foreach(DataColumn column in reportTable.Columns)
    {
        string colName = column.ColumnName;
        if(colName != "Movie Code")
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in reportTable.Rows)
            {
                string value = row[colName]
                if(value.Contains("%"))
                {
                    value = value.Replace("%", "");
                    if(value.Contains("."))
                    {
                        double number = 0.0;
                        double.TryParse(value, out number);
                        value = (number / 100).ToString("0.00##")
                    }
                    row[colName] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return reportTable;
}
```

Now create a function that will create the DataTable from the string values.

```
private DataTable JsonToTable<T>(string data, string html, string tableName)
{   
    DataTable output = null;
    IEnumerable<T> serializedData = data.JsonDeserialize<T>().AsEnumerable<T>();
    List<SelectListItem> colOrder = ParseColumnsToList(html);
    output = serializedData.ToDataTable<T>(colOrder);
    if(output!= null)
    {   
        output = FormatMovieReportTable(output);
        output.TableName = tableName;
    }
    return output
}
```

And now the excel output..

```
private void TableToExcel(DataTable table)
{
    ExcelPackage epackage = new ExcelPackage();
    // the ?? is just in case that the table name is null
    // "new sheet" is just some arbitrary default name
    ExcelWorksheet excel = epackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(table.TableName ?? "new sheet");
    excel.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
}
```

From wherever you called the posted function you can separate the logic

```
private void ThisIsTheCallerMethod()
{
    string data, html, reportName;

    // Other things happen and variables are populated

    DataTable reportTable = JsonToTable<SomeType>(data, html, reportName);
    if(reportTable != null)
    {
        TableToExcel(reportTable);
    }

    // Create the MemoryStream, etc...
}
```